# Why does Instruments UI Automation fail to run on my device?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, user-interface, automation

I have been trying to run a [UI Automation script](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) on my iPad(**iOS 8.1**) for some time and it always crashes with the **message**: `An error occurred while trying to run the script.` **logtype**: `Fail`.

There are no further notes on what went wrong. I also downloaded the crash-logs and opened the console on my MacBook to see what is going on, but I never saw any errors.

Is there a way to figure out was exactly is going wrong and why the **UI Automation** script(javascript) fails? I am running **Xcode 6.1**.

Otherwise I can **build** and **run** my app just fine on the iPad. I am also able to run the exact same UI Automation script in the **Simulator** without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I forgot to activate the **Enable UI Automation** check mark under `Settings > Developer`. It would have been nice by Apple to just point that out and not end in a non-saying error.